# Solr: Facet is not creating any output

Tags: apache, solr

I am using Solr 4.4.0 and running some basic queries. This is what I do when i insert title:* in the query box

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">3</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">title:*</str>
    <str name="indent">true</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
    <str name="_">1430883449558</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="70" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">db01</str>
    <str name="isbn">1933988177</str>
    <str name="author">Michael McCandless, Erik Hatcher, Otis     Gospodnetic</str>
    <str name="author_s">Michael McCandless, Erik Hatcher, Otis Gospodnetic</str>
    <int name="numpages">475</int>
    <str name="description">When Lucene first hit the scene five years ago, it was nothing short of amazing. By using this open-source, highly scalable, super-fast search engine, developers could integrate search into applications quickly and efficiently. A lot has changed since then-search has grown from a "nice-to-have" feature into an indispensable part of most enterprise applications. Lucene now powers search in diverse companies including Akamai, Netflix, LinkedIn, Technorati, HotJobs, Epiphany, FedEx, Mayo Clinic, MIT, New Scientist Magazine, and many others.</str>
    <str name="category">Computers/Programming/Information Retrieval/Lucene</str>
    <float name="price">31.49</float>
    <str name="price_c">31.49,USD</str>
    <arr name="title">
      <str>Lucene In Action, 2nd</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="yearpub">2010</str>
    <date name="pubdate">2010-07-28T00:00:01Z</date>
    <str name="publisher">Manning Publications</str>
    <str name="store">37.763649,-122.24313</str>
    <long name="_version_">1500385802538975232</long></doc>
```

and so on and so forth 70 times...

And this is okay, because this is the result I want(70 books), but when I try to add the facet.field = publisher, it doesn't do anything. It returns the exact same output as above. How can I get this facet to work? the indexing is set to true and everything. what am I doing wrong? Here is an excerpt of my schema:

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="resourcename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="yearpub" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="pubdate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="publisher" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="numpages" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="isbn" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: Set rows to 0 and check what are you getting

Comment: So i'm getting something(finally) but it's all wrong. So for example, one of the publishing companies is called "Cambridge University Press", but the output is split somehow. here's what I mean: <int name="press">8</int> is in one row, <int name="cambridge">1</int> is in another, and <int name="university">1</int> is in the other.

Comment: So it seems to me that somehow the fact that there are blank spaces is causing the error. So for example <int name="Penguin"> 9 </int> is correct output. is there a way to escape the space or something? like read the whole thing until the closing tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change **`text_general`** on publisher field which uses **`WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`** means it splits phrases/strings into chunks whenever it encounters whitespace.

```
<field name="publisher" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

So **Cambridge University Press** is divided into

1. Cambridge
2. University
3. Press

Either remove that tokenizer or use other **`fieldType`** which doesn't use **`WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`**

You can use **`string`** fieldtype so update following and restart Solr and index data again

```
<field name="publisher" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: That's what I was assuming happened. Something with whitespace. So I just tried changing it from text_general to string and still the same problem: It returns it into split categories like you mentioned above. Any other suggestion for type?

Comment: You need to restart solr, then reindex data

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for your help and especially for your patience! I'm a complete solr novice.